# Error Thrown from WCF private method - faultcode=a:InternalServiceFault faultactor=

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have the following code that is executing and calling a private method CreateOrder.  CreateOrder is being called from the web method, but is a private method.  I am receiving the error: "faultcode=a:InternalServiceFault faultactor=" out of CreateOrder.  CreateOrder is not throwing any other exception details.  Is there a problem with passing a guid out of the private?  I have the includeExceptionDetailInFaults set to true, so I don't know if this is an issue of calling that function or if it is an issue of the exception not thrown of CreateOrder appropriately.

```
        Guid OrderResponseTicket;
        String TECCasingType;
        string CurrentAuthCookie = "";

        TECCasingType = CasingType;

        if (Environment.Equals("PROD", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            CurrentAuthCookie = Login(Username, Password, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseIDProd"].ToString(), Environment);
        else
            CurrentAuthCookie = Login("test1@cdi.com", "test1!", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseIDCTE"].ToString(), Environment);

        try
        {
            OrderResponseTicket = this.CreateOrder(inputfile, jobinfo, CurrentAuthCookie, "CASS", TECCasingType, "", ChannelId);
        }
```

Here is the definition for CreateOrder.

```
private Guid CreateOrder(FileObject inputfile, JobInfo jobinfo, string CurrentAuthCookie, String HygieneProcessType, String CasingOption, String SelectedPAF, string ChannelId)
    {}
```

Here is my web.config settings for the ServiceBehaviors...

```
      <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="TECServiceHelperBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <!--<wsdlExtensions singleFile="True"/>-->
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```